# jQuery or Javascript client side image resize before upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

Is there a way to resize images client side before upload (when the user clicks the upload button) so that all fields with `data-type="image"` will execute resizing to the specified dimensions and then commit the upload?

I'm working on a mobile compatible app where users have often to upload images using their mobile camera. It's necessary to reduce the image on client-side to perform quicker uploads of the photos to the server to reduce upload time.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Pre-resize images before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with plan JS by using canvas capabilities of HTML5.

Refere to this answer:
[JavaScript reduce the size and quality of image with based64 encoded code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379027/javascript-reduce-the-size-and-quality-of-image-with-based64-encoded-code)