# Upload multiple images to server in ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a web application that create post with 15 images maximum and other data, I am using AJAX request to send all data with images in one request but I got this error:

> An error occurred during the serialization or de-serialization process with JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set in the MaxJsonLength property.

I am trying to compress the images before uploading but same problem still.
That's the JS code:

```
 function readURL(input) {
    var files = input.files;
    for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        var mainImage = "";
        if (files && files[index]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
                imgElement.src = event.target.result;
                if ($(".imgUpload li").length <= 15) {
                    imgElement.onload = function (e) {
                        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        const MAX_WIDTH = 960;

                        const scaleSize = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width;
                        canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;
                        canvas.height = e.target.height * scaleSize;

                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                        ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                        const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, "image/jpeg");

                        // you can send srcEncoded to the server
                        $(".imgUpload").append('<li class="d-inline-block vTop position-relative mr-3 ' + mainImage + '"><a class="removeImg center w3-text-white fullRadius osRedBg position-absolute" data-ghost="removeImg" href="javascript:;"><svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="20" height="20" class="d-inline-block vMiddle" data-name="IconClose"><path fill="#ffffff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" d="M25.333 8.547l-1.88-1.88-7.453 7.453-7.453-7.453-1.88 1.88 7.453 7.453-7.453 7.453 1.88 1.88 7.453-7.453 7.453 7.453 1.88-1.88-7.453-7.453z"></path></svg></a><img class="ad-img" alt="" src="' + srcEncoded + '"></li>');
                         if ($('.imgUpload li.mainImage').length == 0) {
                    $('.imgUpload li:nth-child(2)').addClass("mainImage");
                }

                if ($(".imgUpload li").length > 2) {
                    $(".imgValMsg").text("@Messages.ClickToDetectMainImage");
                }
                    };

                }
                else {
                    $('.modalCountImgs').modal('show');
                }
                if ($('.imgUpload li.mainImage').length == 0) {
                    $('.imgUpload li:nth-child(2)').addClass("mainImage");
                }

                if ($(".imgUpload li").length > 2) {
                    $(".imgValMsg").text("@Messages.ClickToDetectMainImage");
                }

            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]); // convert to base64 string
        }
    }
}

$("#inputAddImage").change(function () {
    var input = this;
    var files = this.files;
    var validFiles = true;
    for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        var extLogo = files[index].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(extLogo, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
            validFiles = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (validFiles) {
        readURL(input);
        $("#Imgs-error2").removeClass("d-block").addClass("d-none");
    }
    else {
        $("#Imgs-error2").removeClass("d-none").addClass("d-block");
    }
    $("#Imgs-error").removeClass("d-block").addClass("d-none");
});
```

and AJAX request:

```
  //Images
    var lstImgs = [];
    var ImgElements = $(".imgUpload img");
    ImgElements.each(function () {
        var obj = {
            ImageData: $(this).attr("src")
        }
        lstImgs.push(obj);
    });
  
    var productModel = {
        CategoryThirdId: $("#CategoryThirdId").val(),
        ProductTitle: $("#ProductTitle").val(),
        ProductDescription: $("#ProductDescription").val(),
        Price: $("#Price").val(),
      
        Images:lstImgs
    };
            var data = {
                model:productModel
            };
            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateAdvertise", "Advertise")',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res != null) {
                        if (res == "ErrorCatalogName") {
                            $(".danger-product-name").show();
                        }
                    } 
                    else {
                        $(".danger-product-name").hide();
                    }
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
                },
                error: function (res) {
                     $('#overlay').fadeOut();
                }
            });
```

At the end my goal is to upload 15 images and other data from client to server witch I use ASP .NET MVC
and the images to be compressed until the user upload an image with 20 MB.

Comment: The canvas has a very bad compression algoritm and can even increase the image size even if you downscale it. Images are already fairly compressed already and it's tuff for the canvas to compete with that. if you still want to use canvas then look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810740/1008999

Answer (score 0):

You can't post files as string. Use something like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
url: '/Example/SendData',
data: fd,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
```

Comment: I set the maxjsonlength=500000000 and the same problem still appear.

Comment: Try to set manually on the method where you are receiving those files. ```JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = 10000000```

Comment: I go this error: an object reference is required for the non-static field

Comment: Remove ```static``` from method.

Comment: there is no static in the method , that's the method prototype: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateAdvertise(ProductDto model)

Comment: Well, you have to use ```FormData()```, instead of ```JSON.stringfy(data)``` for files, in order to post those files.