# Upload compressed image file from client-side using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, file

I am trying to compress images on client side using JavaScript on some low bandwidth devices and I'm currently stuck in a limbo using the HTML5 File API. I'm new to this, please bear with me if I'm missing something important.

I have some input tags which should ideally open the mobile camera, capture single image, compress and send files to the backend. Although this can be done with a single input field with multiple uploads enabled but I need the multiple image fields to segregate images based on some categories.

Here's the input boxes:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" capture="camera" accept="image/*">...
```

Here's the image compression logic:

```
    // Takes upload element id ("file1") and a maxSize to resize, ideally on a change event
    window.resizePhotos = function(id, maxSize){
            var file = document.getElementById(id).files[0];

        // Ensuring it's an image
        if(file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            // Loading the image
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

                    // Resizing the image and keeping its aspect ratio
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                        max_size = maxSize,
                        width = image.width,
                        height = image.height;
                    if (width > height) {
                        if (width > max_size) {
                            height *= max_size / width;
                            width = max_size;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (height > max_size) {
                            width *= max_size / height;
                            height = max_size;
                        }
                    }
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    var resizedImage = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
                    $.event.trigger({
                        type: "imageResized",
                        blob: resizedImage,
                        url: dataUrl
                    });
                }
                image.src = readerEvent.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    };

    // Function to convert a canvas to a BLOB
    var dataURLToBlob = function(dataURL) {
        var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
        if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
            var parts = dataURL.split(',');
            var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
            var raw = parts[1];

            return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
        }

        var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
        var rawLength = raw.length;

        var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

        for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
            uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
    }

    // Handling image resized events
    $(document).on("imageResized", function (event) {
        if (event.blob && event.url) {
            document.getElementById('file1').files[0] = event.url; // --> Tried this, did not work
            document.getElementById('file1').files[0].value = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(event.blob); // --> Tried doing this looking at some other answers but did not work
            console.log(document.getElementById('file1').files[0]); // Original file is loading fine
            console.log(event.url); // Image compression is working correctly and producing the base64 data
        }
    });

    $(window).on("load", function() {
        // Resets the value to when navigating away from the page and choosing to upload the same file (extra feature)
        $("#file1").on("click touchstart" , function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });

        // Action triggers when user has selected any file 
        $("#file1").change(function(e) {
            resizePhotos("file1", 1024)
        });
    });
```

In PHP script, I'd usually try to catch files from the POST request like:

```
$file1 = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
$file2 = $_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"];
...
```

But this doesn't work because it looks for the original user selected file at a tmp directory (e.g. the actual temporary file in my case is C:\xampp\tmp\php25CB.tmp )

One thing I've tried is put the input fields outside of the form tags, enabled the click behaviour using a button and created new input field with the modified data within the form like:

```
var newinput = document.createElement("input");
newinput.type = 'file';
newinput.name = 'file1';
newinput.files[0] = event.url;
document.getElementById('parentdiv').appendChild(newinput);
```

Needless to say, this had no effect and the PHP script could not identify any file.

Please guide me and suggest any changes required in the JavaScript/PHP script so I can accept the modified file and not the original user uploaded file from the input field.

Comment: Fyi, canvas have a very bad compression and it can increase a well compressed image by a lot: Lets take my gravatar image and make no changes to it and lets see whats happens: https://jsfiddle.net/0mfg8vbk spoiler: size increased by 2.33%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can only change a file input value with another list 
   here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079109/1008999 (also in the example)
2. Using the FileReader is a waste of time, CPU, Encoding & decoding and RAM...
   use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead
3. Don't use canvas.toDataURL... use [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) instead
4. Canvas have bad compression, read earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540150/upload-compressed-image-file-from-client-side-using-javascript#comment119380551_67540150) and see the [jsfiddle proff](https://jsfiddle.net/0mfg8vbk)...
   If you insist on using canvas to try and squeeze the size down then

   1. First try to see if the image is in a reasonable size first
   2. Compare if the pre existing image `file.size` is smaller than what the [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) provides and choose if you want the old or the new one instead.
   3. If resizing the image isn't enough have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810740/1008999) that change the quality until a desired file size & image aspect have been meet.

Without any testing, this is how i would have refactor your code too:

```js
/**
 * @params {File[]} files Array of files to add to the FileList
 * @return {FileList}
 */
function fileListItems (files) {
  var b = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i<len; i++) b.items.add(files[i])
  return b.files
}

// Takes upload element id ("file1") and a maxSize to resize, ideally on a change event
window.resizePhotos = async function resizePhotos (input, maxSize) {
  const file = input.files
  
  if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return
  
  const image = new Image()
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const max_size = maxSize
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  await image.decode()
  let width = image.width
  let height = image.height
  
  // Resizing the image and keeping its aspect ratio
  if (width > height) {
    if (width > max_size) {
        height *= max_size / width
        width = max_size
    }
  } else {
      if (height > max_size) {
          width *= max_size / height
          height = max_size
      }
  }
  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)
  const resizedImage = await new Promise(rs => canvas.toBlob(rs, 'image/jpeg', 1))
  
  // PS: You might have to disable the event listener as this might case a change event
  // and triggering this function over and over in a loop otherwise

  input.files = fileListItems([
    new File([resizedImage], file.name, { type: resizedImage.type })
  ])
}


jQuery($ => {
  // Resets the value to when navigating away from the page and choosing to upload the same file (extra feature)
  $('#file1').on('click touchstart' , function(){
    $(this).val('')
  })

  // Action triggers when user has selected any file 
  $('#file1').change(function(e) {
    resizePhotos(this, 1024)
  })
})
```

Comment: Your answer is really thorough and I learned some great new things. Thank you for that. Just for information, since you didn't test this code, I've replaced the `image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` with `image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file[0])` and it worked great for my purpose. Thank you again.

Comment: Just a quick question, I tried to display the canvas image onto an existing canvas id within the same _resizePhotos_ function after the line `canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)` but it didn't work for me. Is there a way to render the image onto an existing canvas id in the same page?

Comment: In my example i create a canvas element, you would have to do something like `canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')`