# Image resize in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-resizing

I have JavaScript which sends an image to a server.
This works fine but I would like to have the image resized before it is sent.
Here is my working code:

```js
function sendFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
    ws.send(document.getElementById('filename').value);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();
    reader.loadend = function () {
    }
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        rawData = e.target.result;
        ws.send(rawData);
        // alert("the File has been transferred.")
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

How can I resize the image, please?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884245/11634507

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize a Base-64 image in JavaScript without using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958078/resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas)

Comment: Thanks for the quick respose but where does the // Use it like that : resizedataURL('yourDataURIHere', 50, 50); function call go?

Comment: just a heads up, canvas can increase the size (even after croping/resizeing)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810740/1008999