# Code/Resize massive image in Base64 using ionic or angular9 (NOT using Javascript)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, base64, angular9, image-compression

I am getting an massive image in **ionic**,so I need to code or resize it. I am quite lost... is it possible? My code so far is:

```
base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64, ';
defaultAvatar = './assets/img/resources/img-avatar.png';

if (this.staffService.getStaff() === null) {
      this.staffService.staffInfo().subscribe(data => {
        this.staffData = this.staffService.mapStaffData(data);
        this.avatar_imagen = this.staffData.image ?
          this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
            this.base64 + this.staffData.image
          )
          : this.defaultAvatar;
      });
    } else {
      this.staffData = this.staffService.getStaff();
      this.avatar_imagen = this.staffData.image ?
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          this.base64 + this.staffData.image
        )
        : this.defaultAvatar;
    }
```

Used languages must to be **Ionic** or **Angular**. (NOT using **Javascript**)
Thanks you all.

Comment: it looks like  that this code is just getting an image from the server. Where is your code of resizing?

Comment: Thanks for reply @StepUp. It is. I found a few solutions using angular JS, and after researching I found another solution using a library beside. I wrote this post hoping someone can give any clue.

Comment: image resizing can mean different things, you should be very specific. You only want to reduce height and width or you are talking about compressing in terms of resolutiion. In the code above you are only making a url. For width height normal css in template will do. For resolution better go for a library then writing the whole stuff again by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @AakashGarg. I am looking basically obtain less size of the file.

Comment: Hello @EliasMP please refer to my answer below if you want to do it without library.

Comment: @EliasMP checked out my answer? if it worked for you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: @EliasMP: All JS functions are available in TS. There is no typescript specific lib to achieve what you want

Comment: @David I didnt know. So if you want to resize an image in ionic must to use JS? Well, I dont have idea what I will do but Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use use `ng2-img-cropper` to resize the image before uploading. In addition, you can customize dimension.

You can install the package named as `ng2-img-cropper`:

```
npm install ng2-img-cropper --save
```

[You can read more about ng2-img-cropper here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-cropper)

If you want to avoid additional packages, then 
[you can use this TypeScript version of image resizing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235724/1646240)

Moreover,  [there is a little bit simplier example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379027/javascript-reduce-the-size-and-quality-of-image-with-based64-encoded-code). However, you also need to create somewhere canvas and you can use `ViewChild` to work with it.

Comment: Could avoid of using additional package? (just asking)

Comment: @EliasMP please, see my updated answer

Comment: This part is typescript? const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

Comment: @EliasMP you can change this code to Angular version and use `ViewChild` and go  further.

Comment: @EliasMP I've added less verbose example to my reply. Please, see my udapted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Quite lost now, I can´t find your updated answers without use JS. Sorry...

Comment: @EliasMP read from this *Moreover, *. You can convert JavaScript to TypeScript. TypeScript is a JavaScript but with more features.

Comment: @StepUp- You hace to understand I am quite newbie in angular and ionic. I receive a small introduction of them and then start code. No idea of JS. I will try it but it doesnt look like I will go to good port. Thanks anyway :)